# Implementing covariance by hand

Tags: r, statistics, covariance

I made a curious observation today - I implemented the covariance of two vectors 3 different ways, and got 2 different answers. In R, methods 1 and 2 are the same. Method 3 ought to be mathematically the same, but somehow it returns a different number. What is the bug here?

```
# Make some data
set.seed(100)
n = 100
foo = rnorm(n)
bar = rnorm(n)

# method 1
cov(foo, bar)

# method 2
sum(
  (foo - mean(foo)) * (bar - mean(bar))
) / (n-1)

# method 3
(
  sum(foo*bar) - 
    mean(bar)*sum(foo) -
    mean(foo)*sum(bar) + 
    mean(foo)*mean(bar)
) / (n-1)
```

Comment: Method 3 is not the same as others.  Try `foo = c(2,2)`  `bar = c(2,3)`.

Comment: Thank you for catching the bug, there's an `n` missing

Comment: My answer just crossed with your comment ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot that the *mathematical* expression `sum_{i=1}^n mean(foo)*mean(bar)` comes out to `n*mean(foo)*mean(bar)`, not `mean(foo)*mean(bar)` ...

```r
(sum(foo*bar) - 
    mean(bar)*sum(foo) -
    mean(foo)*sum(bar) + n*mean(foo)*mean(bar))/(n-1)
```